# Inconsistent stdout on Python subprocess.popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to execute below system command using python :

```
cat txt_file | egrep "keyword1|keyword2|keyword3"
```

using below python code :

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen (['cat', txt_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen (['egrep', "\"" + keyword_list + "\""], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

#where keyword_list is : "keyword1|keyword2|keyword3"

p1.stdout.close() #for p2 to exit if SIGPIPE from p1
out = p2.communicate()[0]
```

There are multiple lines for the egrep output, But using the above script I'm able to get only the line matching the middle keyword2 in the variable `out`.

What might be the issue here?

Update :
Platform : windows
txt_file is quite big ~8 MB

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is the `"\""`stuff (which would look nicer as `'"'`, BTW).

You are calling `Popen()` *without* `shell=True`, so you should give the parameters as you want them. On a normal `egrep` call the `""` are stripped away by the shell, a step which you don't have here. SO you don't need them here.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by the following workaround:

```
#Using file as stdin for p2
txt_file = open ('txt_file_path')
p2 = subprocess.Popen (['egrep', keyword_list, stdin=txt_file)
out = p2.communicate()[0]
txt_file.close()
```